# Телеграмм и библиотеки

Tags: java, telegram

Я не понимаю разницы между [TDLib](https://telegram.org/blog/tdlib) и [TelegramAPI](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api). Я работаю с Java и мне удалось найти реализации: [для TDLib](https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java) и [для TlgrmAPI](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi).

Для себя я ещё не решил: что есть что? Что из этого библиотека? Что - лишь набор интерфейсов? Почему JNI присутствует в одной библиотеке, а в другой - нет.

Объясните, пожалуйста, что есть что. TDLib, как мне известно, новее чем TlgrmAPI, так ли это? Я хочу понять всю разницу!

Конкретно: мне нужен инструмент для создания приложения, которое поможет мне с пересылкой сообщений из публичных каналов (с целью экономии времени и для удобства). По факту нужен инструмент для получения сообщений, который я способен читать сам (в телеграмм клиенте). Что из этих двух вариантов будет проще?